# Separate the "youtube-dl -g" results

Tags: youtube-dl

I am using the following command:

```
youtube-dl -g "video-url" > file-path
```

and I want to separate the two results into two different files; how would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be perfect, but it does the job:

```
urls=$(youtube-dl -g "video-url")
echo $urls | grep -m 1 https > file-path1
echo $urls | grep -m 2 https | tail -n1 > file-path2
```